# Cannot find the google repositroy in android studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, configuration

Following the instructions in here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/firebase

"First make sure you have installed Google Repository version 26 or higher, using the following steps:

Click Tools > SDK Manager.

Click the SDK Tools tab.

Check the Google Repository checkbox, and click OK.

Click OK to install.

Click Background to complete the installation in the background, or wait for the installation to complete and click Finish."

I am left with this:

[image]

Does anyone know why I can't find the correct SDK tool to download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those instructions look drastically out of date to me.  Firebase (and Play services) no longer distribute their libraries with an Android Studio download.  They use the Google maven repo now.

If you want to integrate Firebase into your app, start with the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).  I suggest not using the Firebase assistant in Android Studio at all, and instead make the changes to your project manually.